# Getting all methods with custom attribute in c# never finds a method

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, reflection, custom-attributes

So I created this function to get all methods with the custom attribute `ExecuteFromConsole`

```
    [ExecuteFromConsole("test", "help")]
    static void Test(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test Ran");
    }

    public void AddAttributeCommands()
    {
        //get all methods with the execute attribute
        var methods = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                               .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                               .Where(x => x.IsClass)
                               .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
                               .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExecuteFromConsoleAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() != null);

        //adds them to commands
        foreach (var method in methods) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Found attribute");
            ExecuteFromConsoleAttribute attribute = (ExecuteFromConsoleAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExecuteFromConsoleAttribute), false).First();
            if(!method.IsStatic)
            {
                Debug.LogError("ExecuteFromConsoleAttribute must be used on static functions only");
                continue;
            }
            CommandFunc func = (CommandFunc)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(CommandFunc), method);
            AddCommand(attribute.command, func, attribute.help);
        }
    }
```

Which worked just fine when I initially tested it but now it will never enter the foreach loop and `Debug.log("found attribute")`  meaning its not finding the method that is clearly right above it with the attribute. 
AFAIK I didn't modify anything that should have affected this.

Does anybody have an insight on why its not working or if I'm going about it all wrong and there is a better way that I should have been doing instead?

The project is in unity if that affects anything

Comment: Binding flags (overload parameter to GetMetho)- you need nonpublic and static

Comment: Thankyou! my test function was public before which is why it must have worked then, adding the flags fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for`GetMethods` is "anything public", but your method is non-method. Try adding `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static` to the `GetMethods` call, to give it more of a hint.